# Mysql explain output show key to be null when using inner join instead of left join

Tags: mysql, explain

This is my query when using join to get product name

```
from 
  invoice a 
  join invoice_detail b on a.invoice_id = b.invoice_id 
  join product i on b.product_id = i.product_id 
where 
  c.store_code in ('70002157','70002158','70002159')
  and a.invoice_date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' and '2022-01-31'
```

and when I use explain keyword, the output show null on key field and type is ALL, and if I execute this script, then it take endless loop.

But when I change from inner join to left join

```
from 
  invoice a 
  join invoice_detail b on a.invoice_id = b.invoice_id 
  left join product i on b.product_id = i.product_id 
where 
  c.store_code in ('70002157','70002158','70002159')
  and a.invoice_date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' and '2022-01-31'
```

then the key field show PRIMARY and type is eq_reff. and query successfully executed
can anyone explain why this happened ?

Comment: normally a query does start with the keyword: `SELECT`.  The result of the optimizer does (also) depend on the selected fields.   BTW: `c.stored_code`?  Where do you select from a table with that alias ?

Comment: `select 
  a.invoice_date as 'INVOICE DATE', 
  a.invoice_number as 'INVOICE NO', 
  i.product_id as 'PRODUCT ID', 
  i.product_code as 'PRODUCT CODE', 
  i.product_name as 'PRODUCT NAME', 
  b.cbp 
  b.qty_drop 
  b.qty_return_bs 
  b.qty_return_good`

this is part of select statement

Comment: when using a left join, the database needs to get all records from `invoice_details`, and when using an (inner) join, only the records that also exist in `product` will be fetched ,which should be less records => more efficient.

Comment: Please post the table definitions (SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name)